# Finding the distribution function of $X^+$ and $X^-$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

As the title implies, if $X$ has a distribution function, I need to find the distribution functions of its negative and positive parts, $X^-$ and $X^+$, respectively.

This is what I've done so far:

Denote the distribution function of $X^+$ as $F^+$. The events $\{X^+\leq x\}$ and $\{X\leq x^+\}$ are identical, i.e., \begin{equation} \{X^+\leq x\}=\{\max(X,0)\leq x\}=\left\{X\leq \max(x,0)\right\}=\{X\leq x^+\}. \end{equation}

So, the distribution function of $X^+$ is $$F^+(x)=P\left(X^+\leq x\right)=P\left(X\leq x^+\right)=F(x^+)$$ Now if $x\geq 0$ then $x^+=x$, and so $F^+(x)=F(x)$. If $x<0$ then $x^+=0$ and so, $$F^+(x)=F(0)=0$$

My problem is that I have doubts if $\{X^+\leq x\}$ and $\{X\leq x^+\}$ are indeed identical. I'm particularly not sure of the part where $$\{\max(X,0)\leq x\}=\{X\leq \max(x,0)\}$$

And IF it is indeed true, can I find the distribution function of $X^-$ using the same process?

Comment: Why $F(0)=0$? This holds if and only if $X>0$ almost surely, in which case there is not much to discuss. Rather, $[X^+\leqslant x]=\varnothing$ hence $F^+(x)=0$ if $x<0$, and $[X^+\leqslant x]=[X\leqslant x]$ hence $F^+(x)=F(x)$ if $x\geqslant0$.

Comment: Concerning the last equality in your question: if $x<0$ then the LHS is $\varnothing$ but the RHS is $\{X\leq0\}$ and is not necessarily empty.

Comment: If you know how to find $F^+$ (see comment of Did) then you can make use of $X^-=(-X)^+$ in order to find $F^-$.